# learning and expanding a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in process of learning more about javascript plugins and found one that is of interest to me.  I am willing to get my feet dirty and see how this thing can be modified...

```
(function( $ ){
  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 

     return this.each(function(){ 
     var $this = $(this),
         data = $this.data('tooltip'),
         tooltip = $('<div />', {
           text : $this.attr('title')
         });

     // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
     if ( ! data ) {

     console.log('still working..'  );
       /*
         Do more setup stuff here
       */

       $(this).data('tooltip', {
           target : $this,
           tooltip : tooltip
       });

     }
   });

},
show : function( ) {
  console.log('this is the show');
},
hide : function( ) { 
  // GOOD
},
update : function( content ) {
  console.log('this is the update');    
  // !!! 
    }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

// Method calling logic
if ( methods[method] ) {
  return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
} else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
} else {
  $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
}    

  };
   })( jQuery );
```

**ok I have 4 questions...**
1.how do you initialize this plugin?  i keep getting 'still working..' with my console log when i try to run a random div element, $('#mtest').tooltip();.

2  the init: is inside the var method, which is private, meaning I can't access init: from outside of this plugin? right? where would i put initializing logic at since it appears to be returning options...?

3.
I am confused about this part of the code...

```
 if ( methods[method] ) {
  return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
} else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
} else {
  $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
}
```

I know its returning all the methods, but...

3a. why write methods[method]// is looks like [method] is an array, and that looks confusing to me because I don't see an array, its a bunch of methods...

3b. what is the else checking for? or why would an error occur?

thanks for any advice on helping me fully understand this plugin!

Comment: Did you look into [jQuery UI Widgets](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory)? I have been looking into this myself recently and started creating some.

Comment: that looks cool, but i don't want a plugin- I'm making too many http requests as it is already and really want to do something on a single js page with little to do with third party extensions... thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your getting at with the first question. But the other questions can be solved pretty easily.

First, lets go over 3.

The code you have, and what jQuery provides in their docs, is merely a sort of "getter" between you and your methods. Instead of clustering up a namespace with all of your methods, you put your methods into an object title `methods` (which is instantiated on the second line of your first block of code.

If you look at the jQuery provided code you are asking about, its not *returning* methods as you've thought. Its *calling* the method of the *key* in your `methods` object. The first if statement says that if you call your plugin (in your case, tooltip) with a *string* variable, it will look up that index in the methods object and *Call* the function.

The second *else if* block says that if you pass a *object* as a parameter OR no parameter, it will call your *init* method. This is sort of like a custom built getter/initializer for your plugin.

So now, to answer your second question, the *init* method can be accessed by either calling your *tooltip* plugin with..

1) no parameters

2) a object parameter (usually options such as `{"someOption":true,"anotherOption":400}`)

3) the string 'init' as in `$('#id').tooltip('init')`

This way you can also access your *show* and *hide* methods with...

`$('#id).tooltip('hide')` ... and so forth.

You can read up on this in the jQuery docs for much more detail. This is me merely putting it into layman's terms.

Comment: "The first if statement says that if you call your plugin (in your case, tooltip) with a string variable, it will look up that index in the methods object and Call the function. " what is the index, what is the methods object and the function, in my case...? thanks

Comment: The *second* line in your first code block is the variable `methods`. That variable happens to be an object that is populated with *methods*. That would be you methods object, right?

Comment: yes, and it is a parent var object for all the inner functions, such as init:, hide: and update.

Comment: *parent var object*, no...you should look into more of the jQuery docs and javascript syntax. `var methods` is a variable that is an *object*. The *key* for each item in the object is the *method name* (init,show,...), the *value* for each item in the object is the actual *method*. I cant get any more explicit than that.

Comment: I think you need to read up on javascript syntax in more depth. You should research objects in javascript and how they work.

Comment: i've been doing that throughout the course of this week, there is no clear definitions on the web that address the specifics of what i am asking here, which is why i am dependent on developers experience for this speific matter with the use of this specific plugin, such as why would you use an array.protoype.slice for methods in a jquery plugin?  there is no documentation that talks about that or introduces that concept that I have come across. nore one that assumes that is acting as a key and value pair.  thanks for the help.

Comment: Right, but the questions you are asking can be solved by simply understanding the underlying concepts of javascript object notation. If you don't understand how to reference a hashed value in a javascript object then there is no way you can build a plugin.